# Simplify CoffeeScript statement

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to handle a simple case where i could be getting an object, or a dictionary.  So i am either going to get a object like:

```
obj.fields.nick
```

or its going to be a dictionary like

```
obj['nick']
```

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do the following:

```
value = (eval("obj.fields." + field[1]) if obj?.fields ) ? eval("obj['#{field[1]}']")
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
value = (obj?.fields?."#{field[1]}" ) ? eval("obj['#{field[1]}']")
```

But if that worked I wouldn't be writing this post...

I am basically looking for a way to execute a string as part of the if

Comment: Are you using a particular library that stores properties in a `obj.fields` if `obj` is a particular type? If so, perhaps you should check whether `obj` is of that particular type. Or as Ricardo suggests in his answer, check whether `obj.fields` is defined (duck-typing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
value = obj.fields?[field] ? obj[field]
# or
value = (obj.fields ? obj)[field]
```

This is the same as

```
if obj.fields?
    obj.fields[field]
else
    obj[field]
```

There is absolutely no need for `eval`.

Comment: is obj.fields.field the same as obj.fields[field] ?   The first object "fields" is not a dictionary but a class".

Comment: @Nix: Yes.  In CoffeeScript and Javascript, the following are equivalent: `foo.bar` and `foo["bar"]` because every object is really an indexed hash.  And @Ricardo is correct.  Do not use eval.  There is rarely a good case of eval... there is usually a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation construct (`"Equals four: #{2+2}"`) is something that is handled by the coffeescript compiler, and will therefore not work inside an `eval`. But assuming the naming of the stuff inside the string does not change, you could easily rewrite it, so that `eval("obj['#{field[1]}']")` becomes `eval("obj['"+field[1]+"']")`. Assuming I got your question right of course.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  I think you did the opposite of simplifying.

Comment: I assumed you had trouble doing an `eval` with a coffeescript string interpolation in it. My assumption was probably wrong then, and you interpolated string gets "compiled" into the proper js before it is eval'ed.